# Modifying the TYPO3 link parser to automatically generate AJAX links

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, typo3

I hope the title makes my question somewhat clear. My problem with this topic is that after weeks of searching I haven't found any clues where I have to go in order to edit this parser within TYPO3.

(This "parser" [I think I should call it that, feel free to correct me] is the one that turns the links generated per ID in the Backend to the real links sent to the client in the final HTML page)

What I'm trying to do (just in case it might help answer the question): I want to modify this parser in a way that it will automatically create resilient AJAX links to other pages on the same website that will only load the parts that change between the pages, as well as that link should still work normally when JS is deactivated. My question itself is only about the location of that parser so far, not about the programming, but if someone might have a different solution I'll gladly listen to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links are rendered trough typolink or through the menu rendering the most cases. But do not change the core! Rethink. I guess you need a javascript function, which checks if a page is internal and onclick change the request.

You could use

```
page.intTarget = _top
```

for setting an target with internal links. But IMHO you should it only with JavaScript.

Solve this, with an hardcoded html page. If you get it, it will be easy to solve it with TYPO3. IMHO it is not an TYPO3 issue now.

Comment: I see, typolink is the term I was searching, and you are also right that modifying typolink does not seem to be the aproach I'm searching for. Touching typolink in anyway seems to be wrong for what I'm trying.

A JS exclusive solution seems to be a good idea if I can get it working, but for now I have trouble finding a reference for the mentioned function.
If that would work I could change the request on a click event and that would allow me to build something with everything I want without negative side effects.

Comment: jQuery('a').onClick(function() { ... load as ajax via adding f.e. type=200}); Now use type=200 for export content only (this is a different task;)